# PostgreSQL convert month name to number

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a query that returns a field as month and year for example "Nov 2015" I want to get the number for the month, here I have to get number as "11".

Comment: @Vivek.S       Yes. Oct 2015, Jan 2016 etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the to_date function that can parse input in a certain format into a 'real' date. Then with this date you can extract the month from it.

```
select EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date('Nov 2015', 'Mon YYYY'))
```

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html for the formatting syntax and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html for the other datetime functions etc..

Answer (score 4):

> [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html)

```
select to_char(to_date('Nov 2015', 'Mon YYYY'), 'mm') month_no
```

and the query can be

```
select to_char(to_date(your_date_col, 'Mon YYYY'), 'mm') month_no
from table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

If your date is **timestamp** , for example:"2017-01-24 23:00:00-03" (this is timestamp with time zone)

```
select to_char(your_date, 'MM') from your_table
```

Then the result would be in this case: "01"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function **to_timestamp**(text, text) and **extract**(field from timestamp):

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_TIMESTAMP("Nov 2015", "Mon YYYY"));
```

see the documentation for [to_timestamp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-formatting.html) and [extract](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use the basic example of converting a month number to its corresponding month name:

```
SELECT to_char(
    to_date (1::text, 'MM'), 'Month'
    ) AS "Month Name";
```

Result:

```
Month Name 
-----------
January
```