# SQL - Query for Matching Rows in Current Month to All Previous Data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a database of SSL certificate data that is updated once per month. I want to issue an SQL query to obtain all records in my database **only from the month of August** where both the expiry date of the certificate and the company that bought the certificate match a previous month.

For simplicity sake, imagine the database schema is as follows:

```
Subject Organisation | Issued Date | Expiry Date | Issuing Company | Month | Year
```

What I have come up with so far is a bit confusing as I made a new table which just holds the August data. If you know a way to do this without creating a table that would be better. This query below gives me an error indicating that more than one row returned by a subquery has been used as an expression.

```
SELECT * 
FROM AugustTable 
WHERE 
"Subject Organisation" = (SELECT 
                          "Subject Organisation" 
                          FROM AllCertsTable 
                          WHERE ("Month" != 'August' AND "Year" != '2018')
                         ) 
AND 
"Expiry" = (SELECT 
            "Expiry" 
            FROM AllCertsTable 
            WHERE ("Month" != 'August' AND "Year" != '2018')
           )
```

The query below kind of works but I only want the August data, or August + all other data appended to the bottom instead of joining columns from each relation.

```
SELECT * 
FROM AllCertsTable AS A 
INNER JOIN August AS B 
ON (A."Subject Organisation" = B."Subject Organisation" 
    AND 
    A."Valid To" = B."Valid To" 
    AND 
    A."Issuing Company" = 'XYZ'
   )
```

Comment: so you have the expiry date in a date field, but have month and year in their own separate fields? and this is all on one table?

Comment: @SaggingRufus unfortunately I inherited the data this way so I will have to do some cleaning. But the Expiry cooresponds to the actual expiry of the ticket. But the Month and Year coorespond to the month and year that the data was inserted into the database. All of the necessary data is in the AllCertsTable.

Comment: are the month and year fields varchar?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would *really* help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM AllCertsTable a 
WHERE a."Month" = 'August' AND a."Year" = 2018 AND
      (a."Subject Organisation", a."Expiry") IN
         (SELECT "Subject Organisation", "Expiry"
          FROM AllCertsTable act
          WHERE act."Month" <> 'August' OR act."Year" <> '2018'
         ) ;
```

There is no reason at all to create a temporary table just for August records.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort @Gordon. This is exactly what I needed. If I wanted to make sure the "Issuing Company" was XYZ at the time of issuing (before August) and did not care about the Issuing company in the month of August, would this make sense for the nested select:

(SELECT "Subject Organisation", "Expiry"
          FROM AllCertsTable act
          WHERE act."Month" <> 'August' AND act."Year" <> '2018' AND act."Issuing Company" = 'XYZ'
         ) ;

Comment: It seems to make sense to me but the results of the query are not as I was expecting. It seems to only match with the August records which contain XYZ in the Issuing Company column. I would like it to contain ANY company but was originally issued by XYZ.

Comment: @ezeekiel . . . This query has no limitation on the company, XYZ or otherwise.  From your comment, I can't tell if you need a filter on `company` in the outer query or some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT
  *
FROM AllCertsTable AS Aug
WHERE 1 = 1
 AND Aug."Month" = 'August'
 AND EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM AllCertsTable AS Temp
   WHERE 1 = 1
    AND Temp."Subject Organisation" = Aug."Subject Organisation"
    AND ((Temp."Year" = Aug."Year" AND EXTRACT(MONTH, to_date(Temp."Month", 'Month')) < EXTRACT(MONTH, to_date(Aug."Month", 'Month'))) OR 
         (Temp."Year" < Aug."Year"))
 )
```

The query is pretty much self explanatory. You select each row, where a row exists that matches the organsation and the "temp" rows year is smaller or the month is smaller .
Also its much easier to match dates or parts of it when they are represented numerical. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33912225/10285235) to convert the months name to its number.